# What is the term for "fanfiction" in French?

Tags: culture

What is the commonly used term for "fanfiction" in french?

Google gives me an identical translation "fanfiction", but I wonder if this is what French people actually use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is! There is no "official" translation for this word, and like many, it is used as is.

It is one of those words too new for the Académie Française to provide or invent an official way to translate it.

Comment: Exactly. On the internet french people sometimes use the english term "Fanfiction" or "Fanfic", but no french specific word.

Comment: Moreover, as "fan" and "fiction" are both in the French dictionnary with the same meaning as in English, there is no real need for a frenchied translation (which would be... "fiction de fan"?)

Comment: "Fan" est utilisé couramment en français depuis plusieurs décennies, et il n'a jamais eu le sens de "fanatique" mais plutôt celui d' "admirateur" saupoudré d'une notion de dévotion. Les "fanfictions" ne sont pas "des fictions écrites par des fanatiques" mais "des fictions écrites par des admirateurs".

Comment: Je ne vois pas vraiment la plus-value qui serait apportée par ma réponse qui serait un doublon de celle-ci.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a good [article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanfiction) on the topic which references *fanfiction*, the short *fanfic* and the alternate spelling *fan-fiction*. It may be too new for the *Ac*. [indeed](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18723), but maybe not for the OQLF as they came up with [*fanafiction*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26502110) (« Fiction écrite par un fanatique d'une série télévisée, d'un film ou d'un livre donnés, qui en reprend les personnages et l'univers, de façon à créer sa propre histoire. », *GDT*), which is basically the same thing but just more in line with the word [*fanatique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fanatique) in French instead of the loan from the short form for *fanatic* in English (i.e. [fan](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fan)). Take your pick!

Comment: Be careful, it seems that here "fanatique" doesn't mean the same thing in French from France and from Quebec. In French from France a "fanatique" is a crazy person that will take extreme mesures for a cause, and a "fan" is someone who is very fond of something or someone.

Comment: Indeed I think @AnneAunyme is right on this point in particular. _Fanatique_ has a bad connotation in France French it might not have in Québec French.

Comment: It has the same connotation in Quebec. The OQLF is known for being a bit... Fanatic. Also, you will never hear fana-fiction in Quebec. Fanfiction is used.

Comment: @L'adit: Un lien très instructif mais qui ne contredit absolument pas ce que j'ai dit et va même dans mon sens. Je ne sais pas vraiment ce que vous essayez de démontrer mais votre discours agressif ne donne pas envie de s'y intéresser.

Comment: Au TLFi (lien ds. la réponse) : _Il [Zucar] n'avait d'autre passion (...) que le sport (...). Un mordu, un fana; mais théorique et dans l'abstraction_ (Arnoux, _Solde_, 1958, p. 42). Voir aussi [_Larousse_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fana/32802/difficulte). Cqfd.